# Up arrow based command history in console input (Java)

Tags: java, command-line-interface, jline

I am currently using:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

To get user input in Java, but I want to add a way for user to use previous command easily. If users presses `UP key` it should show previous command instead of `^[[A`. It shouldn't suggest after I press `enter`. It should work like in bash. For example, I can type arrow key it displays previous command, I can modify it and then press enter to send command.
Is it possible in Java? I tried using libraries like JLine, but I could get it working.

Comment: I never like to use the word 'impossible' but let's use it here for the sake of helping you. Impracticable

Comment: Can you tell why? I am developing a way to send commands, and it would be really great if this feature would work as I described. Is it possible in other languages? But I would prefer to stay in Java.

Comment: Because it would require native code. So it wouldn't be cross-platform for one thing. It goes beyond key listening to the storage of key strokes